# Database best practices - Status

Tags: database, database-design

I'm creating an application in which objects have a status lookup. To give some context, let's use the following example.

---

A helpdesk application where jobs are created and move through the following workflow:

**New** - Job created but unassigned
**In Progress** - Job assigned to a worker and in progress
**Complete** - Job complete ready for invoicing
**Closed** - Job invoiced

---

So, I create a status table with the following details:

**int** ID
**string** Name

and a lookup column on the jobs table

**int** ID
**string** Name
**int** CustomerID
**int** StatusID -> looks up the status

So in the real world, let's say we have the following requirements.

1. Users need to get a report to show all incomplete jobs (jobs which are either New or InProgress)
2. Down the line, someone will want to add a new status that sits in the middle of completed and closed for example.

So with this in mind, my initial thoughts are to create a new column on the Status table called SortOrder or similar and assign numbers to it such as

**New** - 10
**In Progress** - 20
**Completed** - 30
**Closed** - 40

This would mean that for Case #1 above, I could simply query the database for all jobs whose status is greater than or equal to 30. This would also be great for case #2 because it means that if I introduced a new status in between completed and closed it would not break this report.

I can see that it would come up often in different applications. Has anyone implemented a solution like this or come across this problem before?

Comment: Keeping deprecated data around such as closed jobs will begin to make queries slower and introduce logic equivalent to constantly have to step over dead records.

Comment: Closed doesn't necessarily mean deprecated. In terms of a helpdesk system, allowing techs to look back on job history for a customer can provide a lot of real world use.

Comment: As the system becomes mature over years the database will hold tons of deprecated data with no way of migrating it safely. Designing this migration in early can help the system age gracefully. I never said to get rid of the data, just to not keep it in the main table where query speed is important. Also, you may want to use Dates instead of values for your codes, this way you can track how long each activity took. Adding an extra table for codes might save a few rows, but this will add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is have a single Status table, and a companion Status Group table.

```
create table status_group (
    id integer primary key not null,
    alias varchar(20) not null,
    descr varchar(128)
)

create table status (
    id integer primary key not null,
    status_group_id integer,
    alias varchar(20) not null,
    descr varchar(128)
)
```

Then all of the statuses live in a single spot, but are grouped together vs having a zillion individual ones.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't quite get it. How would this be used in my case?